# how to connect ubuntu to share files of time capsule

Tags: ubuntu, sharefile

I want connect my Ubuntu desktop to share file of time capsule.
but i got this error : 
    Got error "kFPAuthContinue" from server Ubuntu

I try this installation 
[link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55526/cant-connect-to-timecapsule-wifi-network-from-ubuntu)
but i got error in compiling.

thanks all

Comment: and i try this solution
 https://ineed.coffee/418/how-to-automatically-mount-and-umount-apple-time-capsule-on-linux/
but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can find an easy to implement script file [here](https://gigaom.com/2009/05/14/access-your-time-capsule-over-the-internet/).

Comment: at this time I haven't access to mac capsule